# Could comments be allowed from 20+

Tags: support, comments

My opinion is that comment privileges are allowed until 50 reputation for what purpose" The Askubuntu Help Page says:

> Privileges control what you can do on Ask Ubuntu. Gain more privileges
>   by increasing your reputation (points you receive from your fellow
>   users for posting helpful questions and answers):

I think this is an incentive for me and you to be helpful onsite and to research well; and I believe I do. But I don't have a lot of questions.  Posting answers tend to need more attention to a subject than I see others posting them give. And I have learned the rules here at 35. It would be helpful if I could comment on others questions sooner.

I could be more helpful if I could comment without having to climb, as I have a lot of comments that could be made now that I have learned the rules. Can I get some feedback please?

And thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want a few more reputation to get you to 50, editing existing posts to clean up problems is an excellent way to generate small quantities of reputation.

Comment: I guess I could; You afterall have proven useful, helping me with mine, but you were using comments, sigh.